# Gradle war plugin change archivename

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

How can I change the archiveName of war plugin to be something like myproject#0.0.1.war? I do not want to hardcode vesion# and project name. I tried a few like below in IDEA15 but had no luck.

```
war{
   //This throws an error. How can I get baseName?
    archivename = ${baseName}-${appendix}-${version}.${extension}
}
```

> Could not find method $() for arguments
>   [build_7m27o75pa4n005if9xv1c2fmu$_run_closure2$_closure9@73c903a5] on root project 'myproject'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${baseName}` isn't valid gradle/groovy syntax. You can do variable interpolation in strings like this instead: `"$baseName"`

so replace your line with:

```
archiveName = "$baseName-$appendix-$version.$extension"
```

assuming of course, that all of these are valid variables.

Comment: Should be archiveName. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I'm using Gradle 4.8.1. Even though I skip the $version, the archive name is always "$baseName-$version.$extension"